# Tools to partition dynamic disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dynamic-disk

I have a 1 TB hard-disk with windows 7 pre-installed. I would like to delete, resize some partition and create ext3/swap partitions to install linux.

Which tools are available for this ?

I tried gparted, it doesn't work.

Comment: How does gparted fail to do the work? Fails to resize existing partition or doesn't support 1 TB disk at all?

Comment: write warning for all the partition saying cannot find size or something in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the free boot disk here: http://www.partitionwizard.com/ it provides a range of options including converting Dynamic disks to basic disks, should that be the situation you find yourself in.